# Mongoose, can't update model with for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I m doing a javascript function using mongoose to find a group which contains a list of users emails, that part works perfectly. After I want to find each user of the list and add the new group name instead of the old group name, I don't know why, but it doesn't work, the function returns me the group before doing the for loop, and the users are not modified.

Here is my user model :

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    }
    groups           :  { type: [String], default: []}
});
```

And here my Group model :

```
var groupSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    title          : String,
    creator        : String,
    listOfUsers    : { type: [String], default: []}
});
```

And here my function :

```
 Group.findOne({ '_id': groupId}, function (error, group){
                var oldTitle = group.title;
                group.title = req.body.title;
                group.save();
                if(error){
                    throw (error)
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < group.listOfUsers.length;i++){
                    User.findOne({'local.email': group.listOfUsers[i]}, function(error,user){
                        if(error){
                            throw (error)
                        }
                        for(var j=0;j<user.groups.length;j++){
                            if(user.groups[j] == oldTitle){
                                user.groups[j] = group.title;
                                user.save();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return res.json(group);
```

Comment: `group.save` is async operation, use callback or promise there.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to find some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use async to fix the callback problem

```
async.waterfall(
[
  function (callback) {
        Group.findOne({
            '_id': groupId
        }, function (error, group) {
            if (error) {
                throw (error)
            } else {
                callback(null, group);
            }

        })

  },
function (group, callback) {


        for (var i = 0; i < group.listOfUsers.length; i++) {
            User.findOne({
                'local.email': group.listOfUsers[i]
            }, function (error, user) {
                if (error) {
                    throw (error)
                } else {
                    callback(null, user, group);
                }

            });
        }
},
function (user, group, callback) {
        var oldTitle = group.title;
        group.title = req.body.title;

        for (var j = 0; j < user.groups.length; j++) {
            if (user.groups[j] == oldTitle) {
                user.groups[j] = group.title;
                user.save();
            }
        }
        callback(null, 'done');
}
],
function (err, result) {
    console.info("4");
    console.info(err);
    console.info(result);
});
```

forgive me if i made any mistake, it is always hard to write code without data, i hope you will understand how i wanted to solve.

and don't  forget

```
var async = require('async');
```

at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You should do `user.save()` only after for loop is finished. I updated `for` loops with `forEach` which I feel more comfortable to use.

```
Group.findbyId(groupId, function(err, group) {
    var oldTitle = group.title;
    group.title = req.body.title;
    if (group.save()) {
        listOfUsers.forEach(function(groupUser) {
            User.findOne({'local.email' : groupUser}, function (err, user) {
                if(user) {
                    user.group.forEach(function(userGroup) {
                    if (userGroup == oldTitle) {
                        userGroup = group.title;
                    }
                })
                user.save();
                }
            });
        });
        res.json(group);
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({messsage: 'Error while saving group!'});
    }        
});
```